# Conversion of byte array hex to decimal

Tags: c#

I have a byte array with hexadecimal values, for example:

```
var b = new byte[] {0x27, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00};
```

I need to convert this to decimal value, but when I used code below, get unexpected result. **Expected is 295, but result is 654376960.**

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(b);
//int myInt = b[0] | (b[1] << 8) | (b[2] << 16) | (b[3] << 24);
int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `decimal` is a specific data type in .NET (technically `System.Decimal`), and a specific (and the same) data type in C#. You are looking for `int`/`System.Int32`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your understanding of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is wrong - your example *is* in little-endian format already, so you should only reverse it if `BitConverter` expects a *big-endian* format. You just need to invert your condition:

```
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(b);
```

(I'd personally put the body of the if statement in braces and new lines, but that's a different matter.)